# Calling ApiController causes SignalR to stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I have a monitoring/logging hub that uses SignalR (2.2.1) and Azure Mobile App for authentication. Regardless of whether the MobileAppController attribute is present on the ApiController, and even if the ApiController contains no hub calling code, calling /api/values from a browser immediately kills my SignalR hub. I have to restart the web app to get it to work again. In the meantime, the webpages will keep trying to connect/reconnect.

The striped-down controller looks like

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

and I setup WebApi inside of

```
    public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app, IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            //.MapApiControllers()
            .AddTables(
                new MobileAppTableConfiguration()
                    .MapTableControllers()
                    .AddEntityFramework()
            )
            .AddPushNotifications()
            .MapLegacyCrossDomainController()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
        Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());

        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
        {
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
                // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
        }

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
          );
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

SignalR is setup using

```
    public static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app, CustomNinjectDependencyResolver resolver)
    {           
        IKernel kernel = resolver.Kernel;
        var connectionManager = resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
        var heartbeat = resolver.Resolve<ITransportHeartbeat>();
        var hubPipeline = resolver.Resolve<IHubPipeline>();

        kernel.Bind<IConnectionManager>().ToConstant(connectionManager);
        kernel.Bind<IUserIdProvider>().To<ZumoUserIdProvider>().InSingletonScope();

        var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration
        {
            Resolver = resolver,
            EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            EnableJSONP = true,
        };

        hubPipeline.AddModule(kernel.Get<LoggingHubPipelineModule>());

        app.MapSignalR(hubConfig);
    }
```

When I try to go to /api/values, this happens

```
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://kamelos-app.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'xxx.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 768.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated xxx successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' in System.Web.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Web.dll
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://kamelos-app.azurewebsites.net/favicon.ico
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'kamelos-app.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 768.
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated xxx successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
```

Tried downgrading SignalR to 2.1.2 to no avail. Same problem.

**Update.** If a SignalR session is not in progress, and I go to /api/values, there is on WebSocketException in the output log, however, going to the monitor page after that, there is no more SignalR. As for the monitor code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function encodeHtml(html) {
            // html still emits double quotes so we need to replace these entities to use them in attributes.
            return $("<div/>").text(html).html().replace(/\"/g, "&quot;");
        }
        var monitor = $.connection.monitor;
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        monitor.client.logError = function (value) {
            $('#logs').prepend('<li class="error">' + encodeHtml(value).replace('\n', '<br/>') + '</li>');
        };
        monitor.client.logWarn = function (value) {
            $('#logs').prepend('<li class="warn">' + encodeHtml(value).replace('\n', '<br/>') + '</li>');
        };
        monitor.client.logMessage = function (value) {
            $('#logs').prepend('<li class="message">' + encodeHtml(value).replace('\n', '<br/>') + '</li>');
        };
        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }, 5000);
        });
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

But this works until /api/values is called. So I don't think it is because of the monitoring code. Also, when SignalR fails, it fails for the whole server. Coming in from different IP addresses also fails to get a signal from SignalR.

If the monitoring page is not up, then I see

```
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Received request: GET https://kamelos-app.azurewebsites.net/api/values
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Found 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'xxx.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 768.
Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0 : Authenticated Tim Uy successfully using 'Session Cookie' authentication.
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' in mscorlib.dll
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1848204182/ROOT-2-131345909532020945): Loaded 'D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client\v4.0_5.6.2.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
05:32:22.128 [25] DEBUG  ValuesController - requested /api/values
```

**Update2.**
The problem is `config.DependencyResolver = resolver`. When this is commented out SignalR does not crash. I think somehow running apiController causes the resolver to get dumped.

Yes, the moment the ApiController completes, my CustomNinjectDependencyResolver is Disposed. Why does it do that?

Comment: ``at first call, I do get a "Hello message" showing up in my SignalR logging clients (javascript webpages). However, immediately afterwards SignalR calls no longer work.`` please share us the code that you use in html webpage to establish a connection to hub. and please share us the code snippets of calling hub method if you call hub method from your API controller actions to push notification to clients.

Comment: Trial for you: Remove the MobileAppController from your ApiController (it doesn't do much).  Does it still kill your SignalR?  If so, it isn't an azure-mobile-services problem.  Azure Mobile Apps doesn't deal with SignalR any more.

Comment: Fred, do you have a bitbucket username? I can share the repo with you. It is a little complicated as the hub is called by a logger.

Comment: Adrian, indeed it is killed by a call to ApiController (without MobileAppController). I will change the header accordingly.

Comment: @AdrianHall I removed MobileAppConfiguration from my Startup, removed MobileAppControllerAttribute, and took out any zumo-related code from my SignalR, and it still happens. I believe the problem might be in Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication somewhere (which is enabled on Azure).

Comment: @AdrianHall Can I turn on higher verbosity for Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication Verbose: 0

Comment: Verbose is the highest verbosity. If you suspect authentication is causing the problem, can you try turning off auth to see whether that resolves your issue?

Comment: @ChrisGillum That was helpful. I turned off all auth on Azure's side and in the application. This let me debug locally, and without Azure Mobile App auth, I am seeing the same problem. So it is a WebApi/SignalR issue of some sort.

Comment: The problem is    config.DependencyResolver = resolver;

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. :) Could you post the answer to your question below and accept it as the answer?

Comment: I'll write something up in a bit. I still need the DependencyResolver though, I'm not sure why WebApi would call dispose on DependencyResolver.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the offending line is

```
config.DependencyResolver = resolver
```

and that WebApi is disposing the resolver after ApiController is called. See [Why is ASP.NET Web Api's Dependency Resolver being disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444952/why-is-asp-net-web-apis-dependency-resolver-being-disposed)

> "The BeginScope() method is called once per request by the Web API
>   infrastructure and Web API will call IDependencyScope.Dispose() when
>   the request ends."